# MVC2 Page Redirect Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller "Payroll" which calls other controllers based on page requests.

currently i have a view "Proll" where there is a button which is not a submit button.

I want to replace current view with another view "BankMst" when user clicks on the button

This is how i tried

```
function ViewDetails() {
    var pth = siteroot + "Payroll/BankMst";
    //alert(siteroot);
    $('#mainFrame').attr('src', pth);
    //window.location.href = rootPath + "Payroll/BankMst/2";
    return;
}
```

But it loads the current view only instead of BankMst view. Request also goes to the old controller instead of new controller.

am i missing something ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not intend to submit any data, instead of using a submit button, use an ActionLink.

e.g.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Do Something", "MyAction", "MyController")
```

You can always make a link look like a button using CSS.

If you must use a submit button, then you can redirect to the new action server side using the `RedirectToAction` method.

Comment: Thanks but i need to do some local processing before redirection.

Comment: by local processing do you mean client side javascript?  or server side

Comment: Can you not hook into the click event of the link on client side and do your processing?  I don't see how its different than a button.

Comment: yes but i need to alert the user first. and based user decission the redirection need to take place.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest making it a <button> or <a> or whatever you want; and just have your window.location changed at the end of the clientside processing. Use Url.Action("Method","Controller") to get the correct URL to redirect to. something like this: <script> var new_url = "<%: Url.Action("Method","Controller") %>"; /*do some processing */ window.location = new_url; </script>

Comment: i am using var siteroot = '<%=Url.Content("~/")%>';

Comment: the window.location way did not work so i tried assigning it directly to the iframe. But still the same result.

Comment: Is this a framed app?  is the pth string correct url where you want to go ?

Comment: Did you print out / check the value of your 'pth' variable ?  If it is correct and you copy it into a new browser window, does it go where you want it to go?

Comment: As both views have same controller and the controller is invoked nice but view name remains the same. the rootpath returns "/".